# Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions on IndexFacesRequest for Amazon Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition, aws-sdk-net

We are using AWS Face Rekognition service for detecting faces from images. We have a gallery app (web on dot net core & mobile app on flutter) where we wants to offer filter by face. For this we send all the pics one by one to the AWS Rekognition to identify faces and store faces.

We have our dot net core based micro-service that sends pictures in background to identify faces. When we run this for the first time, while sending pictures, we get the response from AWS Face Rekognition service just fine for up to 100 images and identified 200 faces detected from the service. And then we started to face following issue.

On IndexFacesRequest method we are getting..

```
Unable to get object metadata from S3. Check object key, region and/or access permissions
```

[image: Visual Studio screenshot where we get error]

We are using AWSSDK.Rekognition dll version 3.7.10.10 for integration.

We have already tried with suggestions we found on during searching..

1. We make sure that Object key is same.
2. We make sure that public access is enabled in AWS for the S3 bucket we are using.
   [image]
3. Gave public access by defining bucket policy
   [image]

4.We make sure that RegionEndpoint for both client and s3 bucket are some.

5. The IAM user has the right permission defined.
   [image]

Note that bucket versioning is disabled in the bucket we use.

We have already referred these, but unable to resolve this issue we are facing.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1806

We are not sure what is causing this issue and how to resolve this.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That error message is terrible.  The actual AWS error should explain more about whether it's that the resource doesn't exist, you don't have access to verify that it exists, or you don't have access to the resource.  Check Cloud Trial to see the actual event log

Comment: @DanielFarrell Can you guide how do I see actual event log?

Comment: Cloud Trail is another AWS service.  Make sure its enabled in the console then try the operation again and a few minutes later you should get an event

Comment: @DanielFarrell Thanx. Just enabled it. I read the doc but not getting if I need to configure anything to log AWS Rekognition API to it. Does just enabling CloudTrail logs API for Rekognition?

Comment: that's all it It should take https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/logging-using-cloudtrail.html

Comment: Thanks, i hope this gives us clear idea now.